# How to utilize SPI Serial bus on a ATSAMD21G18?

Tags: serial, c++, spi

Like the title suggests, I have a [ATSAMD21G18](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATsamd21g18) microcontroller that I want to interface with a [LTC6803-4](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6803-4.html) chip, but I'm not sure how to set up the SPI bus on the microcontroller, and the datasheet proved too confusing for me to understand.

Comment: `SPI.begin()`...? Or aren't you using the Arduino API?

Comment: i'm not even that far, I dont know how to physically connect them, not sure what pins to use on the ATSAMD21G18

Comment: You connect it to the PAD[x] pins for the SPI port you want to use.

Comment: TBH it looks overly complicated on that chip. I'd choose a simpler chip. Any specific reason why you want to use that particular chip?

Comment: I wanted to integrate BLE, 3 LTC6803-4 ics, a Real time clock and a microsd reader/writer onto the same board, and i figured i would base it off the Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit BLE, but i'm open to recommendations for easier micro controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SPI API provided by Arduino (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SPITransaction) and the command format that the chip wants you to use based on the datasheet. Here's a bit of example code for SPI transaction. Though untested, it's what I understood from reading the datasheet. Written for an Adafruit Feather M0 express (uses SAMD21G18 MCU). For pinout see https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-express-designed-for-circuit-python-circuitpython/adafruit2-pinouts#logic-pins-2-8.

Also note that Analog Devices does provide Arduino-Code for *similiar* devices like LTC6803-2 but not for the -4. Still, you can look how they implemented a driver. See [here](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6803-2.html#product-documentation)

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>

/* pin setup */
int chip_select_pin = PIN_A2;
/* SPI pins labeled "SCK" "MO" "MI" on the Adafruit Feather M0 express board
 * are used implicitly.
 * PIN_SPI_MISO (22),  PIN_SPI_MOSI(23), PIN_SPI_SCK(24),
 * */


#define LTC6803_4_MAX_SCLK_FREQ 1000000
#define LTC6803_4_USED_SCLK_FREQ (LTC6803_4_MAX_SCLK_FREQ/2)

SPISettings settings(LTC6803_4_USED_SCLK_FREQ, BitOrder::MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3);

void start_voltage_adc_conversion(){
    SPI.beginTransaction(settings);
    digitalWrite(chip_select_pin, LOW);
    //STCVAD
    //Start Cell Voltage ADC Conversions and Poll Status, with Discharge Permitted
    uint8_t tranfer_buf[2] = {
            0x10, //CODE
            0xB0 //PEC
    };
    SPI.transfer(tranfer_buf, 2);
    //wait for conversion, just a static time. at least 12 milliseconds.
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(chip_select_pin, HIGH);
    SPI.endTransaction();
}

void read_voltages_1_to_4(){
    //trigger voltage conversion
    start_voltage_adc_conversion();

    SPI.beginTransaction(settings);
    digitalWrite(chip_select_pin, LOW);
    //transfer buffer must have 2 bytes for command
    //and 6 bytes for response (four 12-bit ADC values encoded in 6 registers CVR00..CVR05)
    //plus 1 byte for PEC from chip
    //Read Cell Voltages 1-4, "RDCVA", page 22
    uint8_t tranfer_buf[2 + 6 + 1] = {
            0x06, //CODE
            0xD2 //PEC
    };
    SPI.transfer(tranfer_buf, 9);
    digitalWrite(chip_select_pin, HIGH);
    SPI.endTransaction();

    //recover 12-bit ADC value from C1V[0]..C1V[11] from register values CVR00 and CVR01
    //see datasheet page 24
    uint16_t adc_cell_1 = tranfer_buf[2] | ((tranfer_buf[3] & 0B1111) << 8);
    //adc value to voltage conversion according to page 15
    float voltage_cell_1_millivolt = ((int)adc_cell_1 - 512) * 1.5f ;
    Serial.print("Cell voltage 1: ");
    //print with 5 digits accuracy
    Serial.print(voltage_cell_1_millivolt, 5);
    Serial.println(" mV");
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(chip_select_pin, OUTPUT);
    SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
    read_voltages_1_to_4();
    delay(2000);
}
```